# Apache passphrase working sometimes

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, selinux, mod-ssl

On one of my servers I observe the following problem with SSL passphrase: some certs are passing it without asking for a password, while some others keep asking for it.

I have set it up globally:

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/path/to/passphrase
```

but when I restart `apache`, it is asking me for the passphrase on a few domains which are using the same wildcard certificate.

Any idea what can cause this?

to check passphrase i did run

```
(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.pem | openssl md5 ; openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5) | uniq
```

and i am getting one hash which means they match, passphrase its the same

```
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] Init: Pass phrase incorrect
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
 [Wed Mar 05 17:13:23 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

How could i check if this is caused by selinux policy, when i remove the passphrase all starts working ?
BTW at the moment SELinux its disable on my server

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue, it was due that some certs where singed with different password

`echo "Password \$21"`

and with

`echo 'Password \$21'`

So the backslash in first example was escape for $, and in 2nd example we have backslash and $ used in password.

Writing simple script solve that issue